# Autowired not wiring bean by Type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an interface(`X`) with a method which prints out a `statement` and the interface has 2 implementations of it `X1` and `X2` and there is this class `Y` which has 2 objects of `X` autowired by type for `X1` and `X2` with the interface. i.e, like `private X x;` and `private X x2;` and when I call `x.statement()` it prints the default profile statement but when `x2.statement()` is called it still prints the `x.statement()` print statement instead of `x2.statement()`.
BTW I am using Spring boot.

```
public interface HelloWorldService {
    public String getGreeting();
}

@Component
@Profile({ "default", "english" })
public class HelloWorldServiceEnglishImpl implements HelloWorldService {
    @Override
    public String getGreeting() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}

@Component
@Profile("spanish")
public class HelloWorldServiceSpanishImpl implements HelloWorldService {
    @Override
    public String getGreeting() {
        return "Hola Mundo";
    }
}
```

-

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @Autowired
    private HelloWorldService helloWorldService;

    @Autowired
    private HelloWorldService helloWorldServiceSpanish;

    public void setHelloWorldServiceSpanish(HelloWorldServiceSpanishImpl helloWorldServiceSpanish) {
        this.helloWorldServiceSpanish = helloWorldServiceSpanish;
    }

    public void setHelloWorldService(HelloWorldService helloWorldService) {
        this.helloWorldService = helloWorldService;
    }

    public String sayHello() {
        String greeting = helloWorldService.getGreeting();
        System.out.println(helloWorldServiceSpanish.getGreeting());
        System.out.println(greeting);
        return greeting;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you put your code for X, X1, and X2 in here?

Comment: @Todd I have Added the code

Comment: Where did you configure the profile ?

Comment: The pertinent code would seem to be in Y so I would suggest posting that. Plus information on how you specify the active profile.

Comment: In the properties profile "spring.profiles.active=english"

Comment: If Profile is English you are getting Greeting from spanish bean ? Is it ?

Comment: No. If profile is English I get  greeting from English bean itself but when using the spanish bean it still comes in english bean.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, what makes you think one of the Injected beans will be the 'English' bean and one will be the 'Spanish' bean. You inject two instances of the bean defined by the active profile: the 'English' bean. There is no Bean HelloWorldServiceKannadaImpl active for this profile. So both instances are instances of HelloWorldServiceEnglishImpl.

```
    //this code is not called. The instance variable is auto-wired by field
    //and the auto-wired bean is the only one available: the English one.
    public void setHelloWorldServiceSpanish(HelloWorldServiceSpanishImpl helloWorldServiceSpanish) {
        this.helloWorldServiceSpanish = helloWorldServiceSpanish;
    }
```

How it should be:

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    //will be English or Spanish depending on Active profile.
    @Autowired
    private HelloWorldService helloWorldService;

    public void sayHello() {
        String greeting = helloWorldService.getGreeting();
        System.out.println(greeting);

    }
}
```

In your original code either remove the `@Profile` from the two beans, or change to `spring.profiles.active=english,spanish` and it might work as you expect. Although having both kinds of defeats the whole purpose which is to have dynamically injected bean based on the runtime environment.

Answer (score 0):

At a time, only one Profile will be ACTIVE depending upon the set value, so you either can be able to print English or Spanish, but NOT both as per your config.

You can look at [here](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html) for more details.

Comment: That's absolutely not true. There can be multiple profiles active at the same time. Even in docs you linked `dev` and `hsqldb` are both active.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to inject the two beans of the same type at the same time you shouldn't bind them to profiles: you can assign them different names.

```
@Component("english")
public class HelloWorldServiceEnglishImpl implements HelloWorldService {
    @Override
    public String getGreeting() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}

@Component("spanish")
public class HelloWorldServiceSpanishImpl implements HelloWorldService {
    @Override
    public String getGreeting() {
        return "Hola Mundo";
    }
}
```

then you can inject them with the @Named (java api) or @Qualifier (spring api) (if I remember it correctly) annotation

```
@Named("english") // @Qualifier("english")
@Autowired
private HelloWorldService helloWorldService;

@Named("spanish") // @Qualifier("spanish")
@Autowired
private HelloWorldService helloWorldServiceSpanish;
```